# Как правильно остановить Task?

Tags: c#, task

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task th = new Task(OutHookProc.prockill, cts.Token);
```

Останавливаю так:

```
cts.Cancel();
```

Как правильно остановить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал сделать так как описано [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168669/)

```
 private static bool Round = true;
 static CancellationTokenSource cts;
    public static void Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Run(() => prockill(cts.Token), cts.Token);
    }
    public static void prockill(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (Round)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string str in strArray)
                {
                    Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(str);
                    foreach (Process process in processesByName)
                        process.Kill();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
               cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { Round = false;  }
        }
    }
    public static void Cancel()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
```

Хочу Вашей критики, пинки) хочу понять логику и что не следует делать?!

**[Правка]** Изменил немного код:

```
static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
public static void Start()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => prockill(cts.Token));
}
public static async Task prockill(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken);
            foreach (string str in strArray)
            {
                Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(str);
                foreach (Process process in processesByName)
                    process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // другая ошибка
    }
}
public static void Cancel()
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Вроде работает всё ультра быстро, ничего не глючит. Нужны советы по улучшению, что можно добавить/изменить?!

Comment: Неправильно. `Round` можно убрать. А проверку `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` нужно делать внутри цикла `foreach`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, А в остальном всё нормально?

Comment: Так лучше будет за место `static void prockill` использовать `async Task`  ?

Comment: Вроде код правильный, да. Должен работать.

Comment: @VladD, Работает как часы)

Comment: Тогда ставьте вашему ответу галку

Answer (score 5):

Вы не можете *остановить* бегущий таск точно так же, как вы не можете остановить бегущий thread. Вы можете лишь *попросить* таск остановиться, и надеяться, что он послушает вашу просьбу.

Если метод `OutHookProc.prockill` под вашим контролем, поменяйте его сигнатуру так, чтобы он принимал ещё и `CancellationToken`, передавайте токен ещё и туда, и в методе время от времени проверяйте токен и прекращайтесь работу, если токен запрашивает это. Если вы внутри `OutHookProc.prockill` вызываете другие асинхронные методы, передавайте им токен тоже.

Если метод не под вашим контролем и не предоставляет средств для остановки, остановить его никак нельзя. Единственное, что можно сделать — это проигнорировать результат выполнения таска, но при этом он продолжит бежать в фоне.

Comment: А если у меня просто`public static void prockill(){ while(true) ... // тут просто килл поцессов }`,  что мне сделать лучше?

Comment: @ArteS, вместо `true` проверяй флаг что не надо выходить

Comment: Ну в thread вроде хотя б abort можно сделать

Comment: @ArteS: Например, `while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) ...`.

Comment: @Grundy: Не учите людей плохому, `thread.Abort` делать нельзя.

Comment: @VladD, но если очень хочется - то можно :Р

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, можно и рефлексией менять закрытые поля в чужих классах. Но не нужно :-P

Comment: @VladD, вот, кстати, иногда может быть нужно :)

Comment: @Grundy: Не, это не «нужно», это «нет времени/желания/знаний сделать правильно» :-/

Comment: @Grundy "вредный" поток может и проигнорировать аборт